# prevent contact form 7 from sending spam in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, contacts, spam-prevention

Help, I have a problem using contact form 7 in my website. It always sends email as spam to the gmail account that I set, I have search for solutions and I found out that using akismet, captcha will help. I have tried captha once but it still sends spam .. can you please help me on what to do to prevent contact form 7 on sending the emails as spam . or at least tell me the cause of it thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some searching and found out that Contact Form 7 supposedly offers 3 different ways to help stop spam - Akismet (I definitely recommend), CAPTCHA (if it is text-only and not based on images, that is okay, but CAPTCHA isn't always accessibility friendly), and quizzes.

Does your Contact Form 7 have these features and do you have any (or all) of those features enabled?

Akismet in particular is pretty powerful when it comes to figuring out what spam is and isn't. The addition of a text-only CAPTCHA (eg: Is fire hot or cold?) can then eliminate the spammers that are people and aren't bots (automated spamming methods).

Comment: It's not against bots. His mail is going in the spam box. I guess he just to configure an SMTP.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply .. I have tried akismet .. but it asked me to pay/donate money .. right now I can't do that because in my country online payment isn't that much popular .. can i still use akismet w/o paying??

Comment: @Debflav, did the SMTP you mean is the one that is on the server where my site is located??

Comment: @johnkernelle Yes. But I'm not wrong, your emails go in spam box of your users ?

Comment: @Debflav sorry for the late reply what I did is I have set 1 email address in the cf7 that whenever a user uses the cf7 on my website to send email containing inquiries, suggestions etc, all emails will be sent to that email that i have set. but some of it goes in the spam box. That email account is a gmail account; to reply to users, I simply log in using that gmail account and use gmail to reply to them, since I am using gmail to reply, I doubt that the replies that i have sent will go to their spam boxes . the problem is whenever they uses the cf7 to send email to me, it goes to my spam box

Answer (score 0):

Best option I've found to stop CF7 spam is using WordPress Zero Spam: https://wordpress.org/plugins/zero-spam/ Super effective and has support for CF7 form submissions.

Doesn't require users to complete an annoying recaptcha and has a firewall using popular third-party IP blacklists, integrates with several popular form plugins like CF&, and keeps malicious and spam IPs from ever accessing the site.